# Hadoop namenode not starting with exit code 1

Tags: hadoop, namenode

```
prateek@prateek:~$ start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
pdsh@prateek: localhost: ssh exited with exit code 1
Starting datanodes
Starting secondary namenodes [prateek]
prateek@prateek:~$ jps
11011 SecondaryNameNode
10787 DataNode
11161 Jps
prateek@prateek:~$
```

it starts some times but mostly throws error. formatted namenode also.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this problem. I'm seeing it now as well and it was working ok until I installed Gnome and Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the error is about ssh.

You have to create a localhost ssh. Have you done that? If not then I tell you the simple commands:

```
 - ssh-keygen
 - ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_rsa.pub localhost
```

Now, try to ssh with the localhost, it should be a passwordless ssh. Then try re-starting your namenode and it should work.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem because I am able to ssh my localhost poasswordless and I am still getting this error. I guess its something connected to pdsh that incorrectly parses the exit code.

Comment: it is not related to ssh-keygen. but  I still have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, stop dfs and yarn, using:

`stop-dfs.sh` or (`sbin/stop-dfs.sh`)

`stop-yarn.sh` or (`sbin/stop-dfs.sh`)

then use this code:

```
hdfs namenode -format -force
```

then start dfs and yarn again:

`start-dfs.sh` or (`sbin/start-dfs.sh`)

`start-yarn.sh` or ( `sbin/start-yarn.sh`)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
It was a wrong config file in hadoop/etc/hadoop.
Please check if the hdfs-site.xml and the core-site.xml are correct configured.

Here is my configuration:
hdfs-site.xml:

```
<configuration> 
     <property> 
         <name>dfs.replication</name> 
         <value>2</value> 
     </property> 
     <property> 
         <name>dfs.blocksize</name> 
         <value>134217728</value> 
     </property> 
     <property> 
         <name>dfs.namenode.fs-limits.min-block-size</name> 
         <value>32768</value> 
     </property> 
     <property> 
         <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name> 
         <value>file:///opt/hadoop-3.3.0/hdfs/namenode</value> 
     </property> 
     <property>  
         <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name> 
         <value>file:///opt/hadoop-3.3.0/hdfs/datanode</value> 
     </property> 
     <property>  
         <name>dfs.permission.enabled</name> 
         <value>false</value> 
     </property>   
</configuration>
```

and core-site.xml

```
<configuration> 
     <property> 
         <name>fs.defaultFS</name> 
         <value>hdfs://bd-1:9000</value> 
     </property> 
     <property> 
         <name>hadoop.user.group.static.mapping.overrides</name> 
         <value>dr.who=;hduser=hduser;</value> 
     </property> 
     <property>  
         <name>hadoop.http.staticuser.user</name> 
         <value>hduser</value> 
     </property> 
</configuration>
```

**You have to change the user and the paths!**

In hdfs-site.xml you can see two files are defined there.
(file:///opt/hadoop-3.3.0/hdfs/namenode and file:///opt/hadoop-3.3.0/hdfs/datanode)
Make sure you create these files with

```
mkdir -p /opt/hadoop-3.3.0/hdfs/namenode
```

otherwise you might have permission errors.

You can just

```
chown -R hduser:hduser /opt/hadoop
```

to be sure that all permissions are right.

Make sure you make

```
hdfs namenode -format
```

before starting again.

(THX 2 j.paravicini)